# Karma error when running angular2 tests via jenkins on linux

Tags: angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am seeing the following error when running my angular2 unit tests using karma with jenkins.

My tests run fine when I run them on my local machine (windows), however when running the test via jenkins on linux I get the following error.

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: (msg || "").replace is not a function
at /home/hudson/.hudson/jobs/workspace/pjt/node_modules/karma/lib/reporter.js:45:23
```

My tests are never started any ideas what could be causing this. I took a look at the karma source code and I couldn't figure out why there would be a problem.

```
  return function (msg, indentation) {
// remove domain and timestamp from source files
// and resolve base path / absolute path urls into absolute path
msg = (msg || '').replace(URL_REGEXP, function (_, prefix, path, __, ___, line, ____, column) {
  if (prefix === 'base') {
    path = basePath + path
  }
  // more code here ...
```

I'm using PhantomJS as the test runner just in case that's relevant both locally and on jenkins.

I'd appreciate any pointers as to what may be the issue.

Comment: My first instinct is that your local machine has things available that are not available on the Jenkins build server/slave. Are you sure the buildslave is correctly set up to be able to run the tests? Have you tried running them manually on that server?

Comment: @Cronax I've not got direct access to the jenkins machine sorted just yet, but I am in the process of getting it. I'll try to build manually and keep you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question on this.

Turns out the problem was with my karma files section.

```
  { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/rx.js', included: true, watched: true }
```

The filename for the rx module is node_modules/rxjs/bundles/**Rx.js**

With linux being case sensitive this is the reason it worked on a windows dev environment and failed on the linux build server.

The 404 message for the rx.js file was present in the logs but I missed among a lot of other debug logging.

Lesson learned :)

Answer (score 2):

for anyone following https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed, in my case this error occurred due to this line of code :
https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed/blob/master/karma-test-shim.js#L31.

Updating it to 
`System.import('angular2/src/platform/browser/browser_adapter')` 
 
will rectify the problem. 
Hope it helps someone.