# Karma: Move Folder -> Missing Error Handler on Socket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, angular, karma-runner

I have a set of working, valid unit tests for an Angular 2.0 project run by Karma 0.13.22, connecting to a Chrome 48 browser with Socket.io 1.4.5. I was testing under this configuration, which worked:

```
app/
tests/app
karma-test-shim.js
karma.conf.js
```

Then, without changing any code, I moved one folder:

```
source/app/
tests/app
karma-test-shim.js
karma.conf.js
```

... then I updated [karma-test-shim.js](https://gist.github.com/oliver-spryn/a8c6a9b57675dfe72eb2) and [karma.conf.js](https://gist.github.com/oliver-spryn/0baef42e8f18174125c2) with the new paths.

Now the tests don't even run, and I get this error:

```
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: (msg || "").replace is not a function
  at /home/spryno724/projects/portfolio/node_modules/karma/lib/reporter.js:45:23
  at onBrowserError (/home/spryno724/projects/portfolio/node_modules/karma/lib/reporters/base.js:58:60)
  ... more stack trace ...

11 03 2016 20:24:11.038:WARN [Chrome 48.0.2564 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (1 times)
```

Any idea what is causing this? The **only** thing that changed is the folder path.

---

**A sample from [karma.conf.js](https://gist.github.com/oliver-spryn/0baef42e8f18174125c2)**:

```
files: [
  // Load Angular 2 dependencies and the SystemJS shim
  { pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js', included: true, watched: true },
  { pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js', included: true, watched: true },
  { pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js', included: true, watched: true },
  { pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js', included: true, watched: true },
  { pattern: 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js', included: true, watched: true },
  { pattern: 'karma-test-shim.js', included: true, watched: true },

  // The application and test files
  { pattern: 'source/app/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },
  { pattern: 'test/unit/app/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false },

  // Support for debugging sessions
  { pattern: 'source/app/**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false },
  { pattern: 'test/unit/app/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false }
]
```

Comment: did you update your karma.conf to look at source/app?

Comment: @MorganG Yes I updated karma.conf: https://gist.github.com/oliver-spryn/0baef42e8f18174125c2 That was one of the first things I did. Not sure what you mean by the second question.

Comment: I think this is an issue with Socket.IO it looks like other people are experiencing the same issue in 0.13.18 in this newer version as well.  https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1782 while not the exact same problem, someone reported getting the problem again only 4 hours ago with sockets.  Hopefully someone can chime in with a good answer for this as this is pretty weird.

Comment: See https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1969 (same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817590/karma-error-when-running-angular2-tests-via-jenkins-on-linux)

Comment: @EricMartinez Thanks, I saw those too. My is different.

Comment: @OliverSpryn hard to say, I've never seen that error message before (not mentioning the issue in Karma repo). While you look for the solution you may want to ask for help over there in that same issue, or opening a new one, referencing the other one, or so.

Comment: I have the same problem. I didn't move any folder, I just created completely new project and I couldn't get it running. Please let me know if you find solution!

Comment: Any update on this? I can reproduce the problem 1:1 but also looking for a solution at the moment.

Comment: Anyone find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to your proj at https://github.com/oliver-spryn/portfolio

You can try to change your karma-test-shim.js. Under System.config, change format: 'register' to format: 'cjs'.

I copied your karma.conf.js + karma-test-shim.js and create simple proj to simulate the problem you are having (with fix follow above). https://github.com/phhoangbao/angular2-test