# Angular 2, Karma and PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs, angular, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am learning how to set up Karma with Angular 2 and running into issues.

I followed what Julie did in her [seed project](https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed) and applied it to my project.

All works well in Chrome, but when I want to use PhantomJS I get an error. This also happens in PhantomJS2...

This is the error:

```
[karma]: Karma v0.13.22 server started at http://localhost:9877/
[launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS2
[PhantomJS 2.0.0 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#1yDrSei5NUX4_WYaAAAA with id 93476222
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: (msg || "").replace is not a function  
   at node_modules/karma/lib/reporter.js:45:23
```

karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
config.set({
    basePath : '',
    frameworks : ['jasmine'],
    files : [
        // paths loaded by Karma
        {pattern : 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js', included : true, watched : true},
        {pattern : 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js', included : true, watched : true},
        {pattern : 'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js', included : true, watched : true},
        {pattern : 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js', included : true, watched : true},
        {pattern : 'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js', included : true, watched : true},
        {pattern : 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js', included : true, watched : true},
        {pattern : 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/testing.dev.js', included : true, watched : true},

        {pattern : 'karma-test-shim.js', included : true, watched : true},
        {pattern : 'app/**/*.js', included : false, watched : true},

        {pattern : 'app/**/*.html', included : false, watched : true},
        {pattern : 'app/**/*.css', included : false, watched : true},

        {pattern : 'test/**/*.ts', included : false, watched : false},
        {pattern : 'test/**/*.js', included : false, watched : true},
        {pattern : 'test/**/*.js.map', included : false, watched : false}

    ],

    proxies : {
        "/app/" : "/base/src/app/"
    },

    reporters : ['progress'],
    port : 9876,
    colors : true,
    logLevel : config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch : false,
    browsers : ['PhantomJS2'],
    singleRun : true
})}
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36133360/771848

Comment: Thanks alecxe but my rx is proper case Rx and I tried changing the import in the shim.

Comment: See https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1969

Comment: Thanks Eric, I also tried adding runtime-traceur and running outside of inteliJ but same outcome.

Comment: Have you tried including a bundler like webpack? I had this problem at work like a week ago and i think that solved it. Not sure though. So install karma-webpack and include like so:  preprocessors: {
        "Tests/**/*.js": ['webpack']
    },

Comment: For what it's worth I'm having this exact same issue with ng2 + karma + phantomjs 1 and 2. Chrome and Firefox work fine.

Answer (score 0):

ensure this line in your karma.conf.js

```
{pattern: 'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js', included: false, watched: false}, // PhantomJS2 (and possibly others) might require it
```

this github project works with phantom:

https://github.com/danday74/angular2-coverage/blob/master/karma.conf.js

clone it and have a play